# Convert columns into rows and print the values and value counts adjacent to it in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported a csv into my python code which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         50001:[np.nan,5,np.nan,5,5,np.nan],
         50002:[np.nan,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan,3],
         50003:[np.nan,3,5,np.nan,1,np.nan],

})
```

I want my data to look like this:

[image]

I have written a code for this but I am only getting the score and the value counts. I am not able to get the rule_id column. This is the code I am using:

```
for i in dframe:
    dframe1 = dframe.loc[: , i].value_counts()
    print(dframe1)
```

which gives me a result like:

[image]

If you could help me crack this problem , I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) or [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = (df.melt(var_name='Rule_ID', value_name='Score')
        .groupby('Rule_ID')['Score']
        .value_counts()
        .reset_index(name='Value_Count'))
print (df)
   Rule_ID  Score  Value_Count
0    50001    5.0            3
1    50002    3.0            1
2    50002    9.0            1
3    50003    1.0            1
4    50003    3.0            1
5    50003    5.0            1
```

Or:

```
df = (df.melt(var_name='Rule_ID', value_name='Score')
        .groupby(['Rule_ID', 'Score'])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='Value_Count'))
```